# How to make color changing lights with playerheads in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So i basically want a command that will make this [Yellow Stage Light](https://minecraft-heads.com/custom/heads/decoration/1782-yellow-stage-light) repeatedly, forever, turn into this [Blue Stage Light](https://minecraft-heads.com/custom/heads/decoration/779-blue-stage-light) going back and forth between them

I already have a circuit built at the moment that works as far as triggering command blocks when i need them to be, but the command itself what eludes me.

[image: Redstone Circuit]

also, i want it spawning at `~ ~7 ~-6` from the command block. every second, the block will be replaced again with another command, using the same player heads in reverse order.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made any effort into attempting to solve it on your own? What have you tried? Could you edit your question with the commands you used, and your thinking?

Comment: well, i've tried using setblock, which didn't work, and every time i use fill commands it says "cannot place block outside world" even though my coordinates are good :/

Comment: I also used structure blocks, which actually worked, but i wasn't a big fan of the constant raining of item drops every time a block got replaced

Comment: You still didn't provide the commands you tried. Just the general category. And no, if you get a "can't place outside world" feedback, your coordinates were not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/setblock` command to achieve this as it takes NBT tags as an argument.

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> <block> [dataValue|state] [oldBlockHandling] [dataTag]
```

Also, note that if you are using relative commands, you should note that that "relative" position changes as each command block steps since you can't have more than one command block in a single block.

---

If you want the solution:

> `/setblock ~ ~7 ~-6 minecraft:skull 3 replace {Owner:{Id:"6c4b9de4-d5c4-4f56-ad9e-c3ec2d7423a6",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvYzJjYWE1NGJkMGJkY2ZkNzdjYjA2YzI1OGM3YzViODNiNTI2NzE4ZDA0ZDg0ZTRkMTg3YjZkOTcwMjYyYyJ9fX0="}]}},SkullType:3,Rot:0}`
>
> `/setblock ~X ~7 ~-Y minecraft:skull 3 replace {Owner:{Id:"e940ac4c-f7a9-9a34-e25a-29fdb50a3c47",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvZTYzMGMyOGQ2YzhmZjIxNjZhMWFjYjc5NTMzMjJlOWY2ZDg5OWUyOGM2MWJkM2E3NzZhZTQ3ODQ5YWMyYWEifX19"}]}},SkullType:3,Rot:0}`
>
> Where `x` and `y` is another relative position. So if your second command block is two blocks east, than you would want to want the Y-coordinate increased by 2, etc.

---

Edit: Um...

- <s>Are you running the commands at the same time? Because this means that your change did happen, but it happened too fast to be rendered.</s>
- Have you tried destroying (`/setblock <x> <y> <z> minecraft:air`) and then replacing it? You can do that all in one tick with chained command blocks.

Just two possible causes I could think off the top of my mind.

Comment: yeah, i tried this already, but the blocks dont replace eachother everytime the command cycles without being destroyed manually

Comment: just says "block couldn't be placed"

Comment: Try exactly these commands. You probably didn't have the `replace` parameter.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/setblock <command> <block>[<blockstates>]{<dataTag>}`